# Off by one error deserializing date with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, dropwizard

I have a domain object with a field like:

```
@JsonProperty
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

If I send in a JSON string value of 30/04/1992 I find the value ends up being 29/04/1992 when it's subsequently serialized back out.

Any suggestions? Is this a timezone thing maybe?

Comment: Well a `Date` is just a point in time... what time zone is being applied, and do you know whether it's being applied consistently? I strongly suspect this *is* a time zone issue, but you'll need to find out a bit more about the magic deserialization/serialization, I think...

Comment: Is Json send from a different time zone then received?

Comment: Default TimeZone is "GMT" for deserialization (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L219). Serialization should use the local time zone. Try explicitly setting the time zone on the object mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in my dropwizard Application.run() seems to have fixed it. Incidentally, it seems to be the serialisation on the way out that was the issue (thanks dhke).

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

environment.jersey().register(new JacksonMessageBodyProvider(objectMapper, environment.getValidator()));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not at all sure if this should not be considered a bug in Jackson. Especially since using default = local time is commented out in the source.